# Smart pointers as class members for polymorphism

Tags: c++, templates, stl, polymorphism, smart-pointers

I'm new to smart pointers and I would be really grateful if somebody could give me a hint whether the way I'm handling smart pointers as class members is correct.
More precisely, the solution that I would like to achieve is in the context of class polymorphism and should be ideally exception-safe.

Given a [container of heterogeneuous objects](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/containers.html#faq-34.6) (`std::vector<shared_ptr<CBase> > my_vector`),  the usual way to add elements is: `my_vector.push_back( shared_ptr<CBase>(new CChild(1)))`, so that later on, one can call the member function of the specific derived class by doing: `my_vector[0]->doSomething()`.

1. What I would like to achieve is to add stack objects to the vector and still being able to do polymorphism. Intuitively sth. like: `CChild<float> obj1(1); my_vector.push_back(obj1)`. To solve that, I'm using now the [Virtual Constructor Idiom](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-functions.html#faq-20.8): `CChild obj1(1); my_vector.push_back(obj1.clone());`.
   Note that in `some` of my derived classes, I've static member functions that create objects, e.g: `CChild<float> obj1 = CChild<float>::initType2(1);`
2. Because of requirement issues and also to have a clean interface, I've now a new class `CFoo<T>` that has as data member a smart pointer to the `CBase<T>` class.
    The idea is that besides containing other new private members,
   this class encapsulates/handles the smart pointers to the derived objects, such that I'm allowed to do sth. like:
    `CFoo<float> myfoo(CChild<float>::initType2(1)); my_vector.push_back(myfoo);`. This means that the container is now of type `vector<CFoo<T> >` instead of type `vector<shared_ptr<CBase> >`

It's in this context, that I would like to know how to implement the constructors for a class with `smart pointers` as class members? What about the implementation of the `operator =` following the copy-swap idiom? Below, I give some ilustrations of my class design:

```
template < typename T >
class CBase{
    public:
        CBase(){};
        virtual ~CBase(){};
        ...
        virtual CBase<T> * clone() const = 0;
        virtual CBase<T> * create() const = 0;
};

template < typename T >
class CChild1 : public CBase{
    public:
        ...
        CChild1<T> * clone() const  { return new CChild1<T>(*this); }
        CChild1<T> * create() const { return new CChild1<T>(); }
        static CChild1 initType1(double, double);
        static CChild1 initType2(int);

};

template < typename T >
struct type{
    typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr<T> shared_ptr;
};

template < typename T >
class CFoo{

    public:

        CFoo();
        CFoo( const CBase<T> &, int = 0 );
        CFoo( const CFoo<T> & );
        void setBasePtr( const CBase<T> & );
        void swap( CFoo<T> & );
        CFoo<T> & operator = ( CFoo<T> );
        ...
        ~CFoo();

    private:

        typename type<CBase<T> >::shared_ptr m_ptrBase;
        int m_nParam;

};

template < typename T >
CFoo<T>::CFoo()
    :m_nParam(0)
// How shall I handle here the "m_ptrBase" class member? e.g point it to NULL?
{

}

template < typename T >
CFoo<T>::CFoo(const CBase<T> & refBase, int nParam)
    :m_ptrBase(refBase.clone()), // Is this initialization exception-safe?
    m_nParam(nParam)
{

}

template < typename T >
CFoo<T>::CFoo(const CFoo<T> & refFoo)
    :m_ptrBase(refFoo.m_ptrBase),
    m_nParam(refFoo.m_nParam)
{

}

template < typename T >
void CFoo<T>::setBasePtr( const CBase<T> & refBase ){
    // ??? I would like to do sth. like: m_ptrBase(refBase.clone())
}

template < typename T >
CFoo<T>::~CFoo(){
    // The memory is going to be freed by the smart pointer itself and therefore
    // the destructor is empty, right?
}

template < typename T >
void CFoo<T>::swap( CFoo<T> & refFoo ){
//does this here makes sense?
    using std::swap;

    swap(m_ptrBase, refFoo.m_ptrBase);
    swap(m_nParam, refFoo.m_nParam);

}

template < typename T >
CFoo<T> & CFoo<T>::operator = ( CFoo<T> copyFoo ){
    copyFoo.swap(*this);
    return (*this);
}
```

Below an example on what I would like to intuitively achieve. First, I fill the container with `CFoo<float>` objects that contain smart pointers to derived classes, besides another integer class member (Note that all this is only illustrative).

```
std::vector<CFoo<float> > my_bank;
for (int b=0; b < 3; b++){
   float x = b*sqrt(2);
   my_bank.push_back( new CFoo<float>( CChild1<float>::initType2(x), b) );
}

for (double s= 1.0; s<= 8.0; s *= 2.0){
    my_bank.push_back( new CFoo<float>( CChild2<float>::initType2(x), 0) );
 }
```

Once, the container is filled, I would like to do some operations, calling to `virtual` functions, e.g. `doSomething` that are specialized in each derived class.

```
for (int i=0; i < (int)my_bank.size(); i++){
    int b = my_bank[i].m_nParam;
    CBase<float>* myChild = my_bank[i].m_ptrBase;

    myChild->doSomething( param1, param2, param3, ..., b);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if your original problem makes sense. `vector` is an *owning* container, so you shouldn't have any automatic objects that you put in the container. Why not add the element to the container first and then use that one in place of your original automatic object? Otherwise you can always just insert a copy: `v.push_back(shared_ptr<Base>(new Derived(obj)));`

Comment: @KerrekSB, i didn't understand your first suggestion `adding the element to the container first`? Do you mind in illustrating your suggestion? As for the `copy insertion`, what does the `Derived(obj)` is exactly? How could I also add an object created using the `static function member`?

Comment: For the first point: Instead of saying `Foo x; /* do stuff with x */ v.push_back(new Foo(x));`, you could say: `v.push_back(new Foo); Foo & x = v.back(); /* now use x */` For the second point, what part of it is unclear? I'm just making a straight copy.

Comment: @KerrekSB, thanks! For the second point, imagine I instantiate an object like this: `CChild<float> obj1 = CChild<float>::initType2(1)`. How could I follow this type of instantiation, to do intuitively something like: `v.push_back(shared_ptr<Base>(new CChild<float>::initType2(1)))`?

Comment: Well, I'd make `initType2` return a shared pointer already rather than a naked pointer... but more fundamentally, I just think you might not need any of that wrapper class at all. I don't see how it's useful or which problem it solves that can't be solved much more simply.

Comment: @KerrekSB, note that the static functions such as `initType1` or `initType2`, they both return an `object` and not a `pointer`. Soi, you're suggesting to change the return type? Furthermore, the wrapper also contains its own class members and not only the `shared_ptr`. From your suggestions, the best solution would be then to consider` vector<shared_ptr<CBase<T> >`, right? I was having in mind sth. like: v.push_back(new CFoo( CChild::initType2(1), 20) )

Comment: @KerrekSB In the most simple solution, how could I combine the `static instantiation` of my `init` function members with a `vector<shared_ptr<Base> >` definition? There's no other way than using the virtual-constructor-idiom returning shared-pointers, right?

Comment: I don't really know... everything you write is certainly *possible*, it just strikes me as inelegant and overly complicated. What good is a static instantiation function that returns by value? You might as well just define an appropriate constructor. Polymorphism only works on references and pointers... yes, I'd try and stick with a container of shared pointers directly, but then again, I don't know your full requirements. Perhaps it'd be best if you posted a minimal, complete example of what you *need*, and we can think about a data structure that would best reflect that.

Comment: @KerrekSB,thanks.I recently learn about `static` function members therefore the naive code, it seems then that one needs to return by address?.In regard to what I'm looking for, it's related to this [previous post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939510/case-study-polymorphism-for-image-processing). I've basically a collection of image filters with specific characteristics.And I need to apply each filter to a specific image channel.To handle that, I need a container of filters(filterbank). The Foo class will be a FilterbankElem class, that besides the filter has the specific image channel.

Comment: Hm, I don't necessarily want a *concrete* example, but a *representative* one. Foo and Bar are alright (and even desired), as long as you demonstrate the features you need. Reading through concrete code is usually more tiresome and distracting than thinking about an abstract example. Anyway, I'll try and look at that question later on.

Comment: @KerrekSB, you're right. Concrete examples are hard to follow. I updated my original post above and added some `illustrative` examples on what I would like to achieve. I would be really grateful, if you could give shed some lights on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really don't know how to approach this. I don't understand half the interface requirements you've listed, so consider this an experimental answer that may not relate to your problem at all.

I suggest that you tell me what exactly is missing from my approach, and I can amend it. I'll omit templates for now, since they don't seem to be relevant to the problem.

So, without further ado, the simplest start uses a container of smart pointers:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

struct Base
{
  virtual void f();
};

typedef std::shared_ptr<Base> BasePtr;
typedef std::vector<BasePtr> BaseContainer;

struct DerivedA : Base
{
  virtual void f();
  // ...
};

// further derived classes
```

Usage:

```
int main()
{
  BaseContainer v;
  v.push_back(BasePtr(new DerivedB));
  v.push_back(BasePtr(new DerivedC(true, 'a', Blue)));

  BasePtr x(new DerivedA);
  some_func(x);
  x->foo()
  v.push_back(x);

  v.front()->foo();
}
```

If you happen to have some automatic object somewhere, you can insert a copy:

```
DerivedD d = get_some_d();
v.push_back(BasePtr(new DerivedD(d)));
```

To iterate:

```
for (BaseContainer::const_iterator it = v.begin(), end = v.end(); it != end; ++it)
{
  (*it)->foo();
}
```

**Update:** If you want to initialize an object after construction, you can do something like this:

```
{
  DerivedE * p = new DerivedE(x, y, z); 
  p->init(a, b, c);
  v.push_back(BasePtr(p));
}
```

Or, if the `init` function is virtual, even simpler:

```
v.push_back(BasePtr(new DerivedE(x, y, z)));
v.back()->init(a, b, c);
```

**2nd Update:** Here's how a derived object might look like:

```
struct DerivedCar : Base
{
  enum EType { None = 0, Porsche, Dodge, Toyota };

  DerivedCar(EType t, bool a, unsigned int p)
  : Base(), type(t), automatic_transmission(a), price(p)
  {
    std::cout << "Congratulations, you know own a " << names[type] << "!\n"; }
  }

private:
  EType type;
  bool automatic_transmission;
  unsigned int price;

  static const std::unordered_map<EType, std::string> names; // fill it in elsewhere
};
```

Usage: `Base * b = new DerivedCar(DerivedCar::Porsche, true, 2000);`

**3rd Update:** This one is unconnected, just an illustration of how to use lookup tables in favour of switch statements. Suppose we have lots of similar functions (same signature) that we want to use based on some integer:

```
struct Foo
{
  void do_a();
  void do_b();
  // ...

  void do(int n)
  {
    switch (n) {
      case 2: do_a(); break;
      case 7: do_b(); break;
    }
  }
};
```

Instead of the switch, we can register all functions in a lookup table. Here I'm assuming C++11 support:

```
struct Foo
{
  // ...
  static const std::map<int, void(Foo::*)()> do_fns;

  void do(int n)
  {
    auto it = do_fns.find(n);
    if (it != do_fns.end()) { (this->**it)(); }
  }
};

const std::map<nt, void(Foo::*)()> Foo::do_fns {
  { 3, &Foo::do_a },
  { 7, &Foo::do_b },
// ...
};
```

Basically, you turn static *code* into container *data*. That's always a Good Thing. This is now easily scalable; you just add new functions to the lookup map as they come along. No need to touch the actual `do()` code again!

Comment: thanks! Here are some of the missing things:(1)In some derived classes,I've some `init()` functions that are used as sort-of-constructors.I need them because I've different ways to initialize an object with the same number and type of parameters e.g. `objB.init1(p1,p2); objB.init2(p1,p2); ...` and with a parameter constructor I can't choose the `init()` type, unless using a `switch case` on the constructor, but I would like to avoid that. Here comes the first issue, given that types of initializations, how could I then do sth. like `v.push_back(BasePtr(new DerivedC.init3(true, 'a', Blue)));`

Comment: First off, is it feasible to transform those `init` functions into constructors? Second, if not, then is it the case that the objects can exist in a constructed-but-not-initialized state? (In that case, my usage example already covers how to handle that.)

Comment: to solve that, I thought, I can then use the virtual-constructor-idiom, to do: `DerivedB objB; objB.init1(p1,p2);  v.push_back(BasePtr( objB.clone());`

Comment: That's not solving anything: `objB` appears to be in a constructed-but-not-initialized state after the first and before the second call. There's no reason to complicate matters. If that's an acceptable situation, you can just handle everything like that.

Comment: I added an example for the latter situation.

Comment: thanks for the illustration! (a) why does in the second call the object is not initiliazed (`objB.init1(p1,p2)`)? On the other hand, my `init` functions are not virtual, so i might need to chose the first way to `init` the object after construction. Does the following makes sense: `DerivedE * p = new DerivedE();p->init(a, b, c);v.push_back(BasePtr(p));`, i.e. using the `default constructor` and then calling `init`? Did you put the `{` and `}` on purpose, what does this would mean exactly? The created object is only valid in the current context?

Comment: @Tin: Indeed, if the functions aren't virtual, just create the actual object first, then initialize, and then insert into the container. The extra scope is just for tidiness so that those local variables (namely `p`) don't live any longer than necessary. For instance, you can copy/paste that block with impunity. I don't understand your question (a).

Comment: great!. with creating the object, you mean by doing it dynamically by using either the default or param constructor, right? as in your first solution (it doesn't matter which constructor I use, right?)?. then, in regard to point (a) is just a reply to one of your previous replies (see above: `That's not solving anything: ....`). Then, do you think it would make sense to define the `init` functions as `static member functions` and returning the objects by value? as in my post? when does such a thing would make sense? or usually with static member functions one should return pointers?

Comment: @Tin: Ah, I get it. There's a formal concept of "lifetime" which begins when an object's constructor has finished. From that point on, it is valid within the language to refer to an object. If you add a further `init` function, then your object can be in several different states of readiness: Constructed but not ready (`init` not yet called), constructed and ready (`init` called), constructed and decommissioned (`deinit` called), etc. That separation adds some complexity, and so the resulting usage code becomes more verbose, that's all.

Comment: (I'm still not sure if you actually *need* those `init` functions or if you're just avoiding having to think about refactoring them :-).)

Comment: thanks for bringing some new formal concepts, too! do you think it would make sense to define the `init functions` as static member functions and returning the objects by value, as in my post? when does it would make sense? e.g. `DerivedB obj = DerivedB::init(a,b,c);`. Would it make sense to define this `init` functions as static and returning a `shared_pointer`?

Comment: in regard to the `init` functions I would try to ilustrate. Say I would like to create specific cars.For instance, `Derived b1, b2; b1.initDodge(plateNo, year)`, `b2.initPorsche(plateNo, year)`.With `refactoring` them, you mean, it would be better to separate classes for each of those? e.g `CVehicle`, `CCar: public CVehicle`, and then `CDodge: public CCar`, `CPorsche: public CCar`. For my concrete case, I wanted to simulate the same functionality of the `init` functions given in [Kernel1D](http://hci.iwr.uni-heidelberg.de/vigra/doc/vigra/classvigra_1_1Kernel1D.html)

Comment: @Tin: init return by value: never; return by shared-pointer: perhaps. Refactoring: Not necessarily new classes, but move all the initialization to the *constructor* (as I said three or eight times before): `Derived b1(Dodge, plateNo, year), b2(Porsche, plateNo, year);`

Comment: why does one should never return by value? it's because of efficiency? because of the extra-copy done? in regard to moving all to the `constructor`, thanks! I never thought of combining a  `copy constructor` with a `parameter constructor` (`Derived b1(Dodge, plateNo, year)` here `Dodge` would be the object to be copied with the other additional parameters `plateNo` and `year`)

Comment: Well, maybe not "never", but it just doesn't seem to make a lot of sense: If an automatic object is feasible at all (like the one you get back as the return copy), then there's no need for a separate static initialization function in the first place. You typically only need those if you want *restricted* object creation, like "only dynamic" or something like that, in which case you'd make the constructor private and let the static function return a pointer. As I've now said four or nine times, I strongly believe that you're way over-complicating things :-)

Comment: thanks for the explanation on `static` initialization. One more thing, do you mind in updating your original post to illustrate how the implementation of your constructor would look like to support the object initialization you suggested: `Derived b1(Dodge, plateNo, year), b2(Porsche, plateNo, year);`. I'm struggling a bit on how to move the `init's` to the `constructor`.

Comment: @Tin: Sure. I was thinking that `Dodge` and `Porsche` could just be enum values. If you have anything else in mind, let me know.

Comment: good idea! Internally I'll need then `switch-case` and based on the enum values, I could for instance call the appropriate `void init()` function member, right? (to reuse code). In addition, I read that one should usually use [`initialization lists`](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.6) in the constructors, right? However for this case, I won't be able to do that, right? If for some reason, it's not true what I'm saying, could you pls correct me and eventually give an illustration?

Comment: Yes, switching on the enum value is one option, or dispatching through a lookup table... many ways to skin that cat. I don't know why you would want an initializer list -- do you know what those are for, and do you need any range-based initialization?

Comment: thanks for the ilustration! Do you mind in illustrating a `lookup table`-based initialization? Sorry for taking your time, but it's good to learn new things from more experienced people ;-) In regard to the initialization list, the one thing that I know is that `...initialize as a rule all member objects in the initialization list....` quoting [parashift](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.6)

Comment: OK, I added an example for dispatch through lookup tables. Oh, I misunderstood about the lists. I do indeed already use the constructor initializer lists in the second Update, as you can see.

Comment: thanks! In regard to the initialization lists, I always have the following doubt. Say that car has as class `member` a vector. Given a `enum type` as parameter in the constructor, the way that the vector is going to be initialized will vary (i.e. its size & values). In this case, the vector wouldn't be initialized in the `init.list`, right? but rather in the body of the constructor?  Is that correct? Second, imagine that the Car class has as data member a `door` object, how could I initialized the door object in the initialization list?

Comment: I was working in my design and I came to the point that I really need an intermediate layer,between the BaseContainer and BaseContainerPtr.To follow the example of the Car,imagine you're the owner of a car selling company.Say that your parking place is composed of `ParkingElement` (ID,length,etc.).A `ParkingElement` contains only one `Vehicle`,so the container will be sth. like: `vector<ParkingElem<BasePtr>>BaseContainer;`.The `ParkingElem` has as data member a `BasePtr`.How could I do sth.like: `DerivedE * p = new DerivedE(x, y, z);p->init(a, b, c);v.push_back(ParkingElem(p));`?

Comment: @Tin: Why don't you join the C++ chatroom and we can discuss there?

Comment: I was trying to join a chatroom, but I don't have enough reputation for that (minimum requirement: 20). Do you have any suggestions or is there any other way to chat with you?

Comment: thanks. I'm able to read the posts in the chat, but i'm still not able to post anything. At least, there isn't a textfield where I could write something. Do I need a sort of invitation?

Comment: In my chat-profile i've only 11 of reputation, while in my stackoverflow-profile i've 21. i've tried to login again several times, but still doesn't work :S

Comment: I see. I'm sure it'll come eventually. Try the [manual recalculation](http://stackoverflow.com/reputation) maybe.

Comment: I tried that already. Now, I tried it one more time and now I get the following message: "Reputation cannot be recalculated more than once per day."

Comment: No worries. I'm sure it can wait another day :-)

Comment: to be honest, I wanted to do some progress today and think I've done something useful today. But I'll try then tomorrow, thanks.

Comment: @ KerrekSB,when having an `object` somewhere, besides inserting a copy as in: `DerivedD d = get_some_d(); v.push_back(BasePtr(new DerivedD(d)));` would it make sense to do sth. like: `v.push_back( &d );`? Furthermore, if we've now a `move constructor`, does the overload of the `assignment operator` following the `copy-swap idiom` needs to be changed?

Comment: An also, one more questions, why does the following code `DerivedE * p = new DerivedE(x, y, z);  BasePtr myptr1(p); BasePtr myptr2(p);` does not work, but the following yes: `BasePtr myptr1(p); BasePtr myptr2(myptr1);`. Note that way that `myptr2` is initialized in both cases.

Comment: @Tin: No, you must not pushback `&d` - since you're constructing an owning smart pointer, you must only ever pass pointers to dynamic objects. You mustn't make a smart pointer from the address of a non-dynamic object. Similarly, you can only construct *one* owning pointer from a raw pointer - your second question attempts to give ownership of the same thing to two different owners who both believe they're the sole owners. (On the other hand, you can make copies of the *shared* pointer, because those copies will know of one another.)

Comment: @ KerrekSB, thanks a lot for your clarifications! With copies, you mean by calling the copy-constructor of a `shared smart-pointer`? e.g. `BasePtr myptr1(p); BasePtr myptr2(myptr1)`?